# Resizing groups of objects with fixed height of element in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've got a group of objects which shall serve as a template. I need to be able to resize the group but keep some sub-elements fixed to constrain the template.

Lets say I want to resize the object on the image below. The green area and "window title" should never change in size. Resizing should only affect the grey area.

How do I do this in Illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the only possible solution is to drag that shape to the **Symbol Panel** and ensure you enable the **9-Point Scaling Option**.

Then you would use a Symbol instance when you needed that art.

9-point scaling allows the interior of an object to scale while keeping corners and edges as close to original as possible. Basically, it splits the art into sections and scales each section appropriately.

**[HERE](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2007/04/understanding-9-slice-scaling.html)** is a great explanation of 9-point scaling by Mordy Golding.

Comment: As an addendum to the article by Mordy Golding, the 9-point scaling now works without needing to do a Flash export. I found this video, which explains how the intelligent scaling works in newer versions of Illustrator: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cs5/using-9slice-scaling-options-with-symbols/